# Mass due to the ionization energy of the hydrogen atom from $E = mc^2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, unit-conversion, ionization-energy

Using $ E = mc^2$ I want to calculate a hypothetical mass from the first ionization energy of the hydrogen atom. The ionization energy is given in units of $\rm kJ/mol$ which could seemingly be changed to $\rm eV/atom$ by dividing with 96.5. By dividing this energy in units of $\rm eV/atom$ by $\rm c^2$ I believe I would get the mass in terms of $\rm eV/c^2$. I however do not know how to treat the unit *atom* in the denominator. I do not know how the mass could be represented in standard kilograms either. The exact question is:

> How large is the mass corresponding to the bond energy [sic] of a hydrogen atom?

I arrived at the approximate value $1.510436864 \cdot 10^{-16} \rm eV/c^2$ when $ c = 2.99792458 \cdot 10^{8} \rm m/s$ and the first ionization energy of hydrogen is given as $1310 \rm kJ/mol$. Is this value off? Also, how could I change the units of the mass to kilograms?

Comment: Couple of comments here. First, too many digits in the intermediate steps; yeah, keep one or two extras to avoid rounding errors but don't type out lots of extras: we don't want to look at them and they carry no actual information. Second, right at the beginning you converted joules to electron-volts simultaneously with a change from counting moles to atoms. Now you want to covert electron-volts to joules. Maybe it would be better not to convert them in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you simply convert your energy per mole into energy per atom by diving by Avogadro's number, and then calculate your mass:
$$m = \frac{E}{c^2}$$
using this energy instead.